# Is it possible to make the valuable flair appear smaller?

Tags: support

I´m having some trouble with the [valuable flair](https://superuser.com/users/flair) you can place on your own website. 
I want to place it into the sidebar of my blog. The poblem is, the sidebars width is only 190px. The valuable flair is 210px.

Is it somehow possible to smallen it? I dont want to broaden my sidebar.
For example display it with width 105 and height 30.

For better understandment you can look at it on [my blog](http://diskilla.de). i left it there although it doesn´t fit properly to show you.

edit: I tried defining the .valuable-flair css buit it alway gets overwritten by the Flair-default.css.

Comment: I recommend you ask this question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com, since this is a question about the framework running these sites.

Comment: I thought about posting it here but wasn´t sure... I´m even not sure about stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `!important` in the CSS, like:

```
.valuable-flair{
    width: 190px !important;
}
```

Checkout the "Javascript" section on https://meta.superuser.com/users/flair

> Note
>
> There are a few different default
>   themes you can apply to your flair
>   named: clean, dark, and hotdog. To
>   specify a new theme pass a querystring
>   parameter of theme equal to one of
>   these values. If you want to style
>   your flair manually, specify a theme
>   of none and add CSS to style each
>   element. An example of the CSS styles
>   applied to flair is below.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I knew there must be a way. ;-)

Comment: @Diskilla you're welcome!